# Make visible and invisible imageView by a button

Tags: java, android

I have three Activities with one button in each of them. *Act1* with *btn1*, *Act2* with *btn2*, and *Act3* with *btn3*. I have another Activity as MainActivity with three imageViews: *ImageView1*, *imageView2* and *imageView3*, all of which are initially invisible. I want it so when I click on *btn1* in *act1*, *imageView1* in MainActivity will be visible and when click on btn1 again, *imageView1* will be invisible again. And similarly for *imageView2* and *imageView3*.
I have this code so far:

```
Activity1

public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String visibilityStr = PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

        if (visibilityStr != null) {
            if (visibilityStr.equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(act1.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                visibilityStr = "1";
btn1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img1);

            } else {
                visibilityStr = "0";
                Toast.makeText(act1.this, "it invisibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
btn1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img2);

            }
        } else {
            visibilityStr = "1";
            Toast.makeText(act1.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
btn1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img1);

        }

        PublicSharedPreferences.setDefaults("keyVisibility", visibilityStr, getApplicationContext());

    }
});
}





Activity2

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);


Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String visibilityStr = PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

        if (visibilityStr != null) {
            if (visibilityStr.equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(act2.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
btn2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img1);

                visibilityStr = "1";
            } else {
                visibilityStr = "0";
                Toast.makeText(act2.this, "it invisibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
btn2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img2);

            }
        } else {
            visibilityStr = "1";
            Toast.makeText(act2.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
btn2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img1);

        }

        PublicSharedPreferences.setDefaults("keyVisibility", visibilityStr, getApplicationContext());

    }
});
}



Activity3

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity3);

Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String visibilityStr = PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

        if (visibilityStr != null) {
            if (visibilityStr.equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(act3.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Btn3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img1);

                visibilityStr = "1";
            } else {
                visibilityStr = "0";
                Toast.makeText(act3.this, "it invisibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
btn3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img2);

            }
        } else {
            visibilityStr = "1";
            Toast.makeText(act3.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
btn3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img1);

        }

        PublicSharedPreferences.setDefaults("keyVisibility", visibilityStr, getApplicationContext());
    }
});
}
```

MainActivity  with three imageViews:

```
    ImageView imgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
String visibilityStr= PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

if (visibilityStr.equals("0"))
    imgView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
    imgView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


ImageView imgView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
String visibilityStr= PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

if (visibilityStr.equals("0"))
    imgView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
    imgView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



ImageView imgView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView3);
String visibilityStr= PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

if (visibilityStr.equals("0"))
    imgView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
    imgView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

They work well. But the problem is that when I click on *btn1*, all imageViews in MainActivity change (become visible or invisible) or when I click on *btn3*, all imageViews change. I want it so *btn1* just changes *imageView1* and *btn2* just changes *imageView2* and *btn3* just changes *imageView3*, instead of one of the buttons changing all of the imageViews. How can I do that? Which part of the code is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you only have 1key Preference its all keyVisibility so when you click on any of your button this key changes to either 1 or 0 base on your code

here

```
ImageView imgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
String visibilityStr1= PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility1", getApplicationContext());

if (visibilityStr1.equals("0"))
    imgView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
    imgView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


ImageView imgView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
String visibilityStr2= PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility2", getApplicationContext());

if (visibilityStr2.equals("0"))
    imgView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
imgView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



ImageView imgView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView3);
`String visibilityStr3= PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility3",` `getApplicationContext());`

if (visibilityStr3.equals("0"))
    imgView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
    imgView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and ofcoure you should change the keyVisibility on your act1,act2 and act3

Comment: ya. thats the problem. now how can i define various keys and use theme at btns and images codes? can you help me please?

Comment: you can define unique keys for each imageview. for example image1 and btn1 on act1 will be keyVisibility1 and for image2 and btn2 on act2 will be keyVisibility2

Comment: ya, you right. but the problem is here when i make a unique key for buttons, imageViews dosend accept it,and i dont know why :(   can you please write your email and ill send you the project. change the codes  for me if it possible for you? i will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please do a little more study on Android **SharedPreferences** (how to save/get a sharepreference value properly in/from your local storage).

After you are done with your research, here's some hint for you. Hope you will be able to implement this on your own.

**Save value** - save your boolean value when you click the button

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("IsImageViewVisible", true); 
// use different keys for different imageviews; 
//ex: for ImageView1, use IsImageView_1_Visible; for ImageView2, use IsImageView_2_Visible etc
editor.commit();
```

**Get values** in your MainActivity

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean isImageViewVisible = mPrefs.getBoolean("IsImageViewVisible", false); // here,false is default value
```

Then, check all imageview's **visibility** in MainActivity:

```
if(isImageViewVisible){
  // image is visible
} else{
  // image is invisible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy ,you can use one of this methods

**1 : Shared Preferences :**

in your Activities (Act1,Act2,Act3)

write this codes on `onClick` event :

```
 // on Act1
 final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("mainconf",MODE_PRIVATE);

    buttonOnAct1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check if isVisable and change value
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isImg1Visable",true)){
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isImg1Visable",false).apply();
            }else {
                // show it again 
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isImg1Visable",true).apply();
            }
        }
    });

// on Act2
 final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("mainconf",MODE_PRIVATE);

    buttonOnAct2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check if isVisable and change value
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isImg2Visable",true)){
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isImg2Visable",false).apply();
            }else {
                // show it again 
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isImg2Visable",true).apply();
            }
        }
    });

// on Act3
 final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("mainconf",MODE_PRIVATE);

    buttonOnAct3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // check if isVisable and change value
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isImg3Visable",true)){
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isImg3Visable",false).apply();
            }else {
                // show it again 
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isImg3Visable",true).apply();
            }
        }
    });
```

And code of your `MainActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView imageView1;
private ImageView imageView2;
private ImageView imageView3;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
    imageView3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("mainconf",MODE_PRIVATE);
}


//  important PART OF CODE 
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isImg1Visable",true)){
        imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isImg2Visable",true)){
        imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isImg3Visable",true)){
        imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        imageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

}

**2 : public static Variables:**

write your variables as static
example :

```
// in Your MainActivty under class
public static ImageView imageView1;
public static ImageView imageView2;
public static ImageView imageView3;


 // in your Act1 Act2 Act3

 // for hiding from mainactivity
 MainActivity.imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE
 // for showing on main activity
 MainActivity.imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: it dosent work well. the app crashes. and why you wrote the last part of codes separately? please write theme in Activities. thanks.

Comment: @Nirvana  method 2 works only when the `MainActivity` not `stoped` or destoryed


please comment the full error for me